# addEventListener is not a function error using optional chaining

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I've this google tracking code throw me error of

```
t.addEventListener is not a function
```

code:

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    if (googletag?.pubads) {
      googletag!.pubads()?.addEventListener!('slotRenderEnded', slotRenderEnded);
    }
    return () => null;
  });
```

what's the issue here? I have already used `?` on pubads method.

Comment: That's telling you that the return value of `googletag.pubads()` is not a function. It's not `undefined` or `null` (if it were, thanks to optional chaining, it wouldn't be trying to call `addEventListener` as a function), but it's not a function.

Comment: Side note: Avoid type assertions wherever possible. Rather than the non-nullish type assertion you have in the above (the `!`), ensure that the value isn't nullish. (You've already done that for the one after `googletag`, so you can remove that one.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder does removing the `!` solve the problem? I've no clue why it break, it was fine in my local but not production.

Comment: No, that's a side note. No one here can help with the problem, there isn't enough context in the question (and it would be hard to edit it to give enough context). You have to debug it: Change the code to: `const v = googletag.pubads(); v.addEventListener(`... and use the debugger built into your browser or IDE to put a breakpoint on the `v.addEventListener` line. When the code stops at the breakpoint, look at the value of `v`.

Comment: if ```googletag.pubads() ``` is not a function how come it worked in my local? this issue occasionally failed in production by some users.

Comment: should I do `if(googletag?.pubads && typeof googletag.pubads() === 'function') {}`?

Comment: That's not what it's saying. It's saying that the **return value** of `googletag.pubads()` doesn't have an `addEventListener` function.

Comment: (I edited [my comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67120816/addeventlistener-is-not-a-function-error-using-optional-chaining#comment118642365_67120816), please hit refresh. I hope you sort it out!)

Comment: my code worked even without optional chaining initially but somehow it was reported by sentry it has some issue that's why I added bunch of fallback. As you can see people just use it like I did https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154738/google-publisher-tag-registering-to-events

Comment: is it because react useEffect is rendering multiple time? hmm